# generating multiple 1-d arrays from randomizing an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array of values

```
d = [1,2,3,4,.....100]
```

I am wondering how could I create several 1-D arrays (3,20 or 100) using

```
random.shuffle(d)
```

in a single loop?

Comment: Sorry, what kind of output do you expect? Different length randomized subsets from the input list, where the lengths are known up front? I *think* you want one list 3 with 3 random elements, one with 20 and one with 100, correct?

Comment: You could create an array to store the generated arrays. You would just append the newly generated array to the array holder.

Answer (score 1):

```
import copy, random

result = []
d = range(1, 101)
for i in xrange(100):
    result.append(copy.copy(d))
    random.shuffle(result[-1])
```

Comment: You can use `d[:]` to create a shallow copy too, or use `list(d)`. Shuffling a copy like that is comparable in speed to using `sample(d)`; both create a copy and shuffle that copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) instead, specifying a size:

```
sizes = (3, 20, 100)

random_lists = [random.sample(d, size) for size in sizes]
```

Now `random_lists` contains 3 randomized lists, picked from `d`, with 3, 20 and 100 elements respectively.

If you need a number of shuffled lists with the same length and elements as `d`, use `random.sample()` still:

```
random_lists = [random.sample(d, len(d)) for _ in range(3)]
```

Now `random_lists` consists of 3 lists of 100 elements, each a shuffled *copy* of `d`. From the `random.sample()` documentation:

> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while leaving the original population unchanged. The resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples.